# Trying to make a hangman game. Can't get my playerLives variable to decrease correctly

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a hangman game. So far, I've got it working pretty effectively when it is cycling through the secret word and returning the result. I had my playerLives variable decreasing correctly every time an incorrect answer was submitted too, but when trying to tidy my code up it has stopped working and I can't for the life of me get it to reduce in value at all.

```
def checkSecretWord(secretWord, guess, playerLives):
letterConfirm = False
letterDeny = False
for i in range(0, len(secretWord)):

    if secretWord[i] == guess:
        letterConfirm = True

    if guess not in secretWord:
        letterDeny = True


if letterConfirm:
    print("Correct Guess!")

if letterDeny:
    print("Incorrect Guess! Try again!")
    playerLives -= 1
    return playerLives




def gameRunning():
    gameActive = True
    secretWord = getSecretWord()
    guessed_letters = []
    playerLives = 6
    while gameActive:
        makeBoard(playerLives, secretWord, guessed_letters)
        guess = checkLetter(guessed_letters)
        checkSecretWord(secretWord, guess, playerLives)
        print("You have {} lives reminaing".format(playerLives))
```

the checkSecretWord() function searches through the secret word for the letter that has been input by the user ('guess'). It correctly returns "Incorrect Guess! Try again!" when letterConfirm is true (that is to say, the letter does not match one in the secret word), but it doesn't seem to decrease the value of the variable 'playerLives' by 1 like I want it to.

EDIT: Just to cover my own back - I know "return playerLives == playerLives - 1" makes zero sense and is just awfully written but it was my last desperate attempt before I resorted to asking for help.

EDIT 2: Thanks for the help everyone. Problem sorted and lessons learnt. Cheers.

Comment: `return playerLives == playerLives - 1` ???? that accomplishes nothing. you need `playerLives = playerLives - 1; return`

Comment: you are doing `==` which check equality not assign values. do `playerLives = playerLives - 1` or simply `playerLives -= 1`

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies - see my edit in regards to that piece of code. I have tried both methods you are suggesting and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Also store that value returned by `checkSecretWord`. Otherwise it will be lost. Do, `playerLives = checkSecretWord(secretWord, guess, playerLives)`

Comment: You could also return `True` or `False` from `checkSecretWord()` and do the decrement depending on the return value in `gameRunning()`

Comment: That way you can remove passing `playerLives` to the function

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try that too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've got a few issues here

your first function is empty.  let's fix the tabs on that

```
def checkSecretWord(secretWord, guess, playerLives):
    letterConfirm = False
    letterDeny = False
    for i in range(0, len(secretWord)):

        if secretWord[i] == guess:
            letterConfirm = True

        if guess not in secretWord:
            letterDeny = True


    if letterConfirm:
        print("Correct Guess!")
        return playerLives  #THIS IS THE BIG CHANGE

    if letterDeny:
        print("Incorrect Guess! Try again!")
        return playerLives - 1 #THIS IS THE BIG CHANGE
```

you're treating playerlives like a global variable, you need to rewrite this so that we can increment playerlives properly

```
def gameRunning():
    gameActive = True
    secretWord = getSecretWord()
    guessed_letters = []
    playerLives = 6
    while gameActive:
        makeBoard(playerLives, secretWord, guessed_letters)
        guess = checkLetter(guessed_letters)
        playerLives = checkSecretWord(secretWord, guess, playerLives) # see "the big changes" I made earlier
        print("You have {} lives reminaing".format(playerLives))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly.

Comment: glad it works; please remember to upvote, and accept my answer